# SQLDataAdapter adding a where clause

Tags: c#, sql, sqldataadapter

I have a text box named `recordID`
I have declared a variable called `ID` by using the following:

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(recordID.Text);
```

Finally, I have some code which refreshes a gridview after a button has been clicked which works perfectly, but, brings back everything in the table:

```
        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE", conn))
        {

            // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);

            // Render data onto the screen
            gridSelectID.DataSource = t; 
        }
```

I need this to be altered wherby the query is changed so that it adds a where and filters it on the value of the ID mentioned above (taken from recordID.Text which is a text box)

I have tried this:

```
        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = filter", conn))
        {
            int filter = ID;
            // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);

            // Render data onto the screen
            gridSelectID.DataSource = t; 
        }
```

But it complains with `Invalid Column name 'filter'`
I need this to filter the query by the ID which is declared at the top of the code.

Comment: Look at the DataBase Table Schema or Table Design and see what the column names are that exist in the table you are trying to query, what do you think `SELECT * FROM` means

Comment: The columns are ID, Class, Name. I know that filter does not exist as a column. I want to filter it on the variable named filter that I have declared in the code above. I dont understand how to do this.

Comment: According with the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9.aspx), your syntax is correct. So, I suspect that the error is somewhere else. Is because your "filter" parameter does not have any " ***'*** " around it ?

Comment: you are passing the ID as a `Literal` you need to pass it as a Value/ Param

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't automatically bind variables to your command. You need to do it manually, like:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = @filter", conn))
{
    int filter = ID;
    a.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = '{0}'",ID), conn))            {

            // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);

            // Render data onto the screen
            gridSelectID.DataSource = t; 
        }
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you are trying to use filter before it's declared which is why I'm sure someone downvoted you. Just change it to ID in the using clause and it would work fine.

Comment: This is also a bad pattern to build a SQL string dynamically. Even though it's safe in this context because the value is an integer, it's always better to use a constant statement, and assign values through parameters. If the value was a string instead of a number, this would be open to SQL injection.